# How to change line color in tabular?

Tags: tables, color, rules

How can I change the color of the lines (the frame) in a `tabular` environment? In the following MWE:

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
a&b&c \\ \hline
d&e&f \\ \hline
g&h&i
\end{tabular}
```

I would like the horizontal and vertical lines of the table to have, say a blue color.

Comment: Also see [How to redefine the color of table rules without interfering the content of its cell?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7766/5764)

Comment: yes, the answer is there :)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can use the [colortbl](http://ctan.org/pkg/colortbl) package for this. It works as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{l!{\color{green}\vrule}l}
    \arrayrulecolor{red}\hline
    test & test\\\arrayrulecolor{blue}\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Looks like this:

[image: Array with coloured rules]

Comment: Or the `xcolor` package with the `table` option (internally loading colortbl and giving access to the full `xcolor` capacity).

Comment: the command `\arrayrulecolor{red}` is exactly what i need.

Comment: Note that the `arrayrulecolor` command also applies to the `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` commands defined in the `booktabs` package.

Comment: How do you reset this to the default color afterward? I am guessing that the default is usually black, but I am not sure.

Comment: @RandyCragun Have you found out?

Comment: Yes. An answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468858/get-default-text-color) suggests that the current color is defined as `.`. Thus, `.` is the default color at the beginning of the document. That means that you can define a new color to match `.` at the beginning of the document and then use that color to reset to the default. In the preamble: `\AtBeginDocument{\colorlet{defaultcolor}{.}}`. Where you want to reset the rule color: `\arrayrulecolor{defaultcolor}`.

Answer (score 27):

The [tabu](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabu) package could also be helpful here.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
  \taburulecolor{blue}
  \begin{tabu}{c|c|c}
    a & b & c \\ \hline
    d & e & f \\ \hline
    g & h & i
  \end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: i voted for wh1t3's solution, because, i need this in a very long document, with many tabular that are already written, and i don't want to change the environment. But the package tabu seems looks very interesting. Thank you

Comment: @nicolasroy: You can still *upvote* Thorsten's answer as well of course.

Comment: i've have been fighting in understanding how ot officially registerd in this forum... precisely with this purpose :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  cells = {c},
  hlines = {red3},
  vlines = {blue3},
}
  a & b & c \\
  d & e & f \\
  g & h & i \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]