# Coloring a certain side of a cell in a table

Tags: tables, color, border

I have a standard LaTeX table and want to color a certain side of a cell, like I can do in Excel. Is there a way to do this?

Example of what I mean:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: @Zarko surely you are not suggesting that the tables in the colortbl documentation are not professional looking? :-)

Comment: @Zarko no, it isn't:-)

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40666/how-to-change-line-color-in-tabular