# Horizontal grey line or dotted lines in tabular mode?

Tags: tables

I am curious if anyone has tried modifying the horizontal lines (e.g. \hline) in tabular environment to get a less severe contrast? Perhaps a grey line or dotted line?

Comment: Does this help?: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20140/can-a-table-include-a-horizontal-dashed-line

Comment: For colored line see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40667/101651.