# Get default text color

Tags: color

I want to go (back) to the default text color. If the default color is black then I can use `\color{black}`. But I'm looking for a command for the general case where black may or may not be the default color. Something like `\color{defaultcolor}`.

(I'm aware of the advantages of using `{\color{...}...}` or `\textcolor` instead, but I want specifically `\color{defaultcolor}`.)

**Edit:** I use the `color` package, or probably I could use `xcolor`.

Comment: So how would the default color be defined?  Last \textcolor or last \color?  Why not just use `\def\defaultcolor{black}` (for example)?

Comment: As far as I know, black is always default, at least with `xcolor`.  You didn't specify which package you are getting color from.  With `xcolor`, you could define a default color with `\definecolor{default}{rgb}{0,0,0}` (which is black, in this case)

Comment: @JohnKormylo default color is neither last `\textcolor` nor last `\color`. Default color is the color that would show when not using any `\textcolor` nor `\color`. I don't want to *set* some `defaultcolor` variable. I want to *get the information* about the *currently set* default color, and use it.

Comment: @whatisit I edited the question to add info about packages. I don't want to define a default color. I want to *get the information* about the *currently set* default color.

Comment: @root Which document class are you using?

Comment: @samcarter I'm curious about a general answer for different document classes. Or at least for `article`. In what way does the answer depend on the document class?

Comment: @root I was hoping you'd say something like beamer, than it would have been easy.

Comment: @root Anyway, what do you consider to be the default colour? The colour after the documentclass is loaded or the one active at begin document or the one active after begin document?

Comment: @samcarter I'm curious about `beamer` as well - how does it work there?

Comment: @samcarter Regarding your other comment: All these definitions are fine, I'm curious about info for as many of them as possible.

Comment: @root In beamer you can just use `\usebeamercolor[fg]{normal text}` (or `\color{normal text.fg}` if you prefer this syntax)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both `color.sty` and `xcolor.sty` contain the following two lines:

```
\def\normalcolor{\let\current@color\default@color\set@color}
\AtBeginDocument{\let\default@color\current@color}
```

So at the beginning of the document (after the preamble), `\default@color` is set to `\current@color`. Then `\normalcolor` returns the colour to whatever it was set to in the preamble (or DeviceGray Black if nothing is set in the preamble).

If neither `color` nor `xcolor` are loaded then `\normalcolor` is defined in `latex.ltx` as `\relax`, so it does nothing.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\color{red}
\begin{document}
\color{blue}
Blue
\normalcolor
Normal Colour (Red as set in preamble)
\end{document}
```

This also works in `beamer` when the default text colour is set using `\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=...}`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=red}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \color{blue}
  Blue
  \normalcolor
  Normal Colour (Red as set in preamble)
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

As Devid Purton stated in his answer the default color is the color active at begin of the document (`\begin{document}`). You can access the *current color* by using '`.`' (dot) as color name and store that under a new name using `\colorlet`. Now to define the default color under the color name `defaultcolor` simply add `\colorlet{defaultcolor}{.}` at the begin of the document. This can be done either in the preamble *after* loading `xcolor` with `\AtBeginDocument` or simply adding it directly after `\begin{document}`.

These are features of the `xcolor` package, the older `color` package is not sufficient.

The following example will make blue the default color and switch back to it inside an green text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\AtBeginDocument{\colorlet{defaultcolor}{.}}

\color{blue}

\begin{document}

Some text

{\color{green} Text \textcolor{defaultcolor}{default} Text}

More text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, the *current color* concept is nice!