# Coloring borders of a table

Tags: tables, color

I have to draw a table where I need to color the cells brown and the borders with red. After reading a few similar questions, I have figured out how to properly color the cells and have resolved some issued with my pdf viewer. But I have not found a way to change the borders from black to red.

Please suggest a way to do this. Thank you.

Edit: Adding the packages I have used.
For writing my document I saw a YouTube video and just copied all the packages they had used:

```
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{amsmath}  
\usepackage{amsfonts}   
\usepackage{amssymb}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage{multirow}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide more information about what you've tried so far. In particular, please tell us which color- and table-related LaTeX packages (if any) your document employs.

Comment: Thank you @Mico. I have edited my question to include all the packages I have used.

Comment: Have you seen these answers? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391469/how-to-make-some-border-lines-of-a-table-thick-and-colored/391491 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7766/how-to-redefine-the-color-of-table-rules-without-interfering-the-content-of-its

Comment: @Ingmar, Yes the question you have linked is perfect. Thank you!